# JQuery button does not work

Tags: jquery

it use PHP, JQuery and HTML but the problem is in the button what use JQuery and HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Aircraft Fleet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/flick/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="./jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="./ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
            .button()
            .click(function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>


    <form action="new_aircraft_fleet_process.php" method="post">
    <table>

    <tr><td class="forms">Registration: </td><td><input maxlength="6"  type="text" name="registration" size="15"/></td></tr>

    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Insert Submit"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The button does not work. If you push it, there isn't any reaction. I want what the button do the form.

Comment: event.preventDefault() stop the propagation of the button action..., just remove it.

Comment: Your only code is code that stops a button from working, and you're wondering why it's not working? I'm confused here.

Comment: There is a similar post on [stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741083/cant-get-my-jquery-button-to-go-to-links/17609049#17609049

Plese check the answer!

Answer (score 0):

1.You didn't include `jquery.js` to your source.

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
```

1. You should set your input tpye `button`
2. You should use submit().

   $("form").submit(function() 
   {

   });

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the jQuery Source in the first place..

jQuery UI needs jQuery as an dependency..

```
var $elems = $("input[type=submit], a, button");

$elems.button();

$elems.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});​
```