# Can't get my Jquery button to go to links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uibutton

I am using Jquery to style some buttons for my website and it looks great except for the fact the the buttons do nothing. Here's how I have the buttons setup;

JS

```
$(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
    .button()
    .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<button><li><a href="../home.html">HOME</a></li></button>
<button><li><a href="../commercial.html">COMMERCIAL</a></li></button>
<button><li><a href="../residential.html">RESIDENTIAL</a></li></button>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` would make it do nothing .. maybe you should take that out

Comment: Why would you have a li in a button?

Comment: @PerfectGundam Especially since it's not valid HTML

Comment: Not sure why you're using button tag if it's a link, just use `<a>` and style it in css.

Comment: Explosion Pills -removing that doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I should have noted that I'm a novice. So there's no way to make it work as is? I can go through css....

Comment: also, the original script had a call that turned all a tags into buttons but I only wanted the top row to look like that

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function() {

    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
    .button()
    .click(function( event ) {
var urlink = $(this).attr('href');   
    window.location = $urlink;   
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

```
<ul>
   <li ><a href="somewhere">Home</a></li>
   <li ><a href="somewhere">Commercial</a></li>
   <li ><a href="somewhere">Residential<a/></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know how you are using jQuery to 'style' but I think simple css might just work.
I think you don't need a button.

Or if you need buttons then

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="button" value="Home" name="home"/></li>
    <li><input type="button" value="commercial" name="commercial"/></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[name=home]").bind("click", function(){
                  //submit http request or locatioin.href
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript snippet you have show is from the [JQuery UI Demo page](http://jqueryui.com/button/)

It is using the click event's preventDefault() method to prevent it from activating the click event. This is done so that the demo buttons don't cause the buttons and in particular the input-button to post the event to the server. As this is a demo page, I presume that the makers did not want the events associated with the buttons to be activated.

You can leave out the preventDefault() method and the click event will be activated. Thereafter you will be able to see the pages or associated actions with your buttons. E.g.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button").button().click();
});
</script>
```